# Subtracting 1 from a generic low pass filter

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, convolution, signal-processing, computer-vision

I am taking a Computer Vision class and the following question about Signal Processing and Filter Kernels is asked on the provided slides:

> You are given a generic normalized low pass Filter kernel. Which
>   Filter would be obtained by subtracting 1 from its central element?

However, I do not know the answer to this. Later I was provided with the following master solution:

> Let  $f$ be a generic low pass filter and  $a $ be a generic image,
>   the result of convolving the filter  $(f-\delta ) $ with $a$ is: 
>   $(f-\delta ) *a$ = $f*a-\delta*a = -(a-f*a) $.
>   To derive this expression, we need to use the linearity properties of
>   the convolution and the fact that the convolution with a delta does
>   not alter the original signal. In the end, it results in a high pass
>   filter which inverts the sign of the image (i.e., its phase is delayed
>   by 180 degrees).

But studying the solution I do not understand it either. What exactly is asked and what is meant by subtracting 1 from the central element of a generic low pass filter? How does one come to this solution? Is there maybe a better way to show this?

Comment: The filter is taken to be centered about zero, so $f(0)$ is its central element. Since $\delta(t)$ equals $1$ when $t=0$ and is zero elsewhere, $f(t) - \delta(t)$ is equivalent to subtracting $1$ from $f(0)$. After that, since $a(t) \ast \delta(t) = a(t)$, you get the result given in the solution.